# two issue about install web3.js through and invoke web3.eth.methods

Tags: web3js, contract-debugging, truffle-contract

First, I install type to the code like `npm install web3` in the terminal while the first issue occurs (**Environment1**).Second, I change the version of `node` 、`npm` (like **Envirnment 1**=> **Environment2**) and type to the same code `npm install web3` is OK (version of `web3` is 0.20.6 ). Last, when I invoke web3.eth.methods in my project(**Environment2** ),I found the second issue is occuring that `this.web3` is defined but the `this.web3.eth.methods` is undefined in despite of I configure the environment 2 through `npm install web3` or `yarn add web3` .

**Environment1**
system:Ubuntu16.04; 
node:8.9.0; 
npm:5.6.0;

Issue 1 as fellow
the issue describe like /.npm/_cache/tmp/git-clone-da91fc96/.git:Permission denied
[image]

**Environment2**
system:Ubuntu16.04; 
node: 6.11.0; 
npm: 3.11.0; 
web3: 0.20.6;

Issue 2 as fellow
I type to the code like console.log(`this.web3`) in project and test through developer tool in Google ,the picture as fellow:

[image]

I invoke the contract through `var Contract = new this.web3.eth.contract(artifacts.abi,'contract_address');` print the contract in project and test through developer tool in Google ,the picture as fellow:

[image]

And I invoke a method like `getValue()` is undefined and I type to the code `console.log(window.escrowContract.methods);` display the methods is undefined as fellow:

[image]

I don't know whether relationship has between two issue and I look through some articles and tutorials ,their methods don't work on me .And I know the version of web3 under the version1 (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html) ,the method of invoke contract should be `var Contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(artifacts.abi,'contract_address');` .But a new issue occurs as fellow ,so I change the `C` into `c` .

[image]

What's the method can resolve it ?

Comment: I have resolved this problem through two codes as fellow:
1.npm cache clear --force
2.npm install web3

Comment: Explanation in my opinion as fellow:
First, the first issue occurs because cache of npm is filled in my computer ,before I clear the cache of npm ,I operate the npm install web3 in root directory occurs issue .After I do that, the npm install web3 is OK.

Comment: Sencond, before I operate 'npm install web3', I ever install web3 through 'yarn add web3', but after complete installation, issue2 occurs. I feel that install web3 through yarn is half-baked.
From then on, I type to two code as I said, the two issues don't occur.
These explanation only represent my opinion, I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem through two codes as fellow:
1.`npm cache clear --force`
2.`npm install web3`

Explanation in my opinion as fellow:
First, the first issue occurs because cache of `npm` is filled in my computer ,before I clear the cache of `npm` ,I operate the `npm install web3` in root directory occurs issue .After I do that, the `npm install web3` is OK.
Sencond, before I operate `'npm install web3'`, I ever install web3 through `'yarn add web3'`, but after complete installation, issue2 occurs. I feel that install web3 through yarn is half-baked.
From then on, I type to two code as I said, the two issues don't occur.
These explanation only represent my opinion, I hope it's useful for you.